# Which profile does sh loads

Tags: sh

I am trying to load a specific tool ( [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) ) from within sh.

Installing it as explained in the page for bash it works perfectly and testing it returns the following.

```sh
$ bash
$ nvm --version 
+ X.XX.X
```

but if I type

```sh
$ sh
$ nvm --version
+ sh: 1: nvm: not found
```

but still its expected as the default installation modifies the `.bashrc`.

now i have included the same `.bashrc` code in my `/etc/profile`

```sh
export NVM_DIR="/opt/nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

and tried again.

```sh
$ sh
$ nvm --version
+ sh: 1: nvm: not found
$ echo $NVM_DIR
+ /dir/to/nvm
$ [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && echo "it works?"
+ it works?
$ [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
$ nvm --version
X.XX.X
```

which got me extremely confused. What exactly is happening ? Isn't `sh` loading the `/etc/profile` or am I doing something really wrong?

--edit after comments--

also tried to include it in the local profile

```sh
$ cat ~/.profile
+ export NVM_DIR="/opt/nvm"
+ [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  
$ sh
$ nvm --version
+ sh: 1: nvm: not found
```

Comment: If you vote for closing a question especially for not "following stack overflow guidelines" please provide a feedback on why is that. To either improve the question or explain why. Cause it contains example, research, specific question

Comment: You should append the path `"/opt/nvm"` to the `PATH`  variable when definining in `/etc/profile` i.e. `PATH="$PATH:/opt/nvm"`

Comment: i will give it a try ! but the nvm.sh loads a function in the shell not a binary so the hopes aint high

Comment: [This](https://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html) is a pretty good article about startup files. You'll notice that `sh` might not read `/etc/profile`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. will try to read this one thank you !

Comment: Ah Yes! Ben is right! you should probably add it in user directory at `/home/<user>/.profile`

Comment: @Inian tried it also in ~/.profile and it was not sourced.. I am reading  link and there is a blue line that kinda ... skips the files :/ which is scary

Comment: It's not sourced because an interactive non-login shell started with `sh` (green dashed arrow) only sources whatever the variable `$ENV` points to (see [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03)).

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes its clearly shown into the link you first send as I am following the sh blue line. So I will try to populate the `$ENV` variable before sh. Thank you.

Comment: @BenjaminW. if you would like turn the last one about the `$ENV` into an answer please. just tested `ENV=/etc/profile sh` and it worked !

Comment: I didn't close-/downvote, but the question might be better suited for [unix.se]?

Comment: it could be yes but according to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask my question currently has all the features described in this one.. even so "sh" is actually a tag in stackoverflow thus its "Accepting" questions like that. thats why i am wondering and none of the ppl that voted to close left a feedback.. this is not helpful for the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was described in [this](https://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html) article with the sh blue line. 
The solution to the problem was to set the `/etc/profile/` in the `ENV` variable.

for example `ENV=/etc/profile sh` would load the profile when the sh opens. That solved the problem